# segmentation fault при выводе словаря set

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Решаю небольшую задачку на тему словарей. Писал подульно, чтобы было можно сразу найти ошибки. Стал тестировать. В некоторых случаях выдаётся ошибка при вызове функии Print. Суть блока кода такая. Есть некий словарь словарей строк. В нём сейчас имеется некоторое количество элементов. На вход подаётся 2 строки, если первая строка есть, тогда создаётся временная переменная, в которой дабавляются все значения что были в этом элементе словаря. Затем удаляется этот элемент словаря и добавляется новый. Если в элементе словаря только 3 элемента или меньше, ошибка на первое добавление не срабатывает и всё выводится. При следующем добавлении, уже вылетает данная ошибка. Никак не пойму в чём дело...

```
void PrintSet(const set <string> &vectStr){
    for(auto s: vectStr){
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}

void Print(const set<set<string>> &input){
    for(auto s : input){
        PrintSet(s);
    }
}

//проверка есть ли элемент в словаре
bool FindInSet(const set<string> &setStr, const string &inputWord){
    return setStr.count(inputWord);
}

//ADD word1 word2 — добавить в словарь пару синонимов (word1, word2)
void Add(set<set<string>> &input){
    string word1, word2;
    cin >> word1 >> word2;
    set <string> words;
    words.insert(word1);
    words.insert(word2);
    set <string> tmp;
    bool check = false;// нет в словаре

    for(auto s :input){
        if(FindInSet(s, word1)){
            tmp = s;
            for(auto add : words){
                tmp.insert(add);
            }
            input.erase(s);
            input.insert(tmp);
            check = true;
        }
    }
    if(check == false){
        input.insert(words);
    }

}

int main() {

    set<string> test = {"word", "words", "worde", "wow", "wwooccwoowo", "woccw", "wwccoowoowo"};
    set<set <string>> test1;
    test1.insert(test);
    Add(test1);
    //Add(test1);
    cout << "end" <<endl;
    Print(test1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (auto s :input){
  ...
  input.erase(s);
  ...
}
```

Вы удаляете из `input` текущий итерируемый элемент контейнера. После этого поведение не определено. Все падает.

Range-based for цикл не является каким-то "волшебным" циклом, в котором можно делать что угодно. Range-based for - это не более чем "синтаксический сахар" для обыкновенного цикла с итератором. Этот итератор просто скрыт от ваших глаз. Уничтожив текущий элемент контейнера, вы сделали этот внутренний итератор невалидным. Далее все накрылось.

Не надо пользоваться range-based for в ситуациях, когда вы собираетесь модифицировать итерируемый контейнер.

P.S. У вас передача параметров везде выписана "по ссылке", чтобы избежать создания копий, а итерирование везде тупо делается по значению, создавая на каждой итерации никому не нужные копии "тяжелых" объектов. Раз уж вы умеете передавать аргументы по ссылке, то и итерировать, наверное, по ссылке должны уметь?

Comment: Спасибо, понял) буду пробовать)